# prove the following by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $M = p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot \dots \cdot p_n$, where $p_1, \dots, p_n$ are distinct primes.

Prove by induction that, for all positive integers $n$, if $\gcd(a, M) = 1$, then 
$$a^{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)(p_n-1)}\equiv 1\pmod M$$

I have no clue where to even start (i.e. the base case).

Please help!

Comment: Do you know a theorem that says something about $a^{p-1}\bmod p$ when $p$ is a prime?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: hey..yh I am haha

Comment: How would I use the said theorem in this particular situation?

Comment: You would apply it, one prime at a time, and then combine the results with the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Do you know that Theorem?

Comment: yh, I knw the CRT

Comment: Then you should be all set.

Comment: m still a little confused but less stuck, so thnks